# Python, Answer not splitting right

Tags: python

i have a little software made with python language.
Behavior:

1. Starts
2. Choose a random number from 1 to 100
3. ask me to input a try.
4. It will output a messsage:

   - 4.1 It will print you the number of tries you've done
   - 4.2 it will print you all the entries of the user.
   - 4.3 It will ask you to replay again

The problem is within the section 4.2 Where the print of all the input of the user are displayed like this

```
Vos essais: 33 44556677798082848687887079747271
```

Instead of

```
Vos essais: 33 44 55 66 77 79 80 82 84 86 87 88 70 79 74 72 71
```

I have tried everything to make it works but all the space im trying to add just separate each characters of the print. ( ive join join(). Split()) nothing seems to works fine.

I know the full code is not professionnal, but I'm a beginner.

```
        liste = tentative
        for i in str(liste):
            total = total + i
            message = total
    print("Bravo vous avez devinez mon choix après", "\x1b[0;33;40m" + str(compteur) + "\x1b[0m",\
"\x1b[0;33;40m"+ "essais!" + "\x1b[0m", "\nVos essais:", str(premieressaie), str(message))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this section of your code:

```
    liste = tentative
    for i in str(liste):
        total = total + i
        message = total
```

You are iterating through each letter of the last guess and just adding each digit. You should add a space as well. Instead, you could just do this:

```
message += str(tentative) + ' '
```

**However**, that's not the most pythonic way to solve this problem. It would be better to keep track of all of your guesses. Then, when you print it out, you can join them as a string. Like this:

```
guesses.append(str(tentative))
```

and then when you want to print out the list, do this:

```
print ' '.join(guesses)
```

Answer (score 1):

i've made it the simplest way possible and remove the for to just use this line like mentionned by

```
message += str(tentative) + " "
```

It's working super fine and simple enough for what i have to do.

Thanks everyone for the quick answer

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have a giant string with all the digits.

```
container=[]
yourstring="your string here"
for i in range(len(yourstring)):
    try:
        container.append(yourstring [i:(i+2)])
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

`tentative = int(input("Votre essai svp: "))`, so tentative is the str representation of whatever number the usr inputed.

When you do

```
    liste = tentative
    for i in str(liste):
        total = total + i
        message = total
```

You are looping through every character of liste.

If the second number the user input is 44 then on the first loop `i` is 4, total = "4" and message = "4". On the second loop, `i` is again 4, the total becomes "44" and message = "44"

If the third number is 55, then on the first loop `i` = "5" and total = "445", and on the second loop total = "4455". When you 'add' characters you do not add a space in between them.

To solve this, you could add a space yourself outside the for loop `total += " "`.

Also, the `message` variable is redundant with `total`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the numbers guessed by the player, then use a list.  Here is code where I have replaced **total** with a list, and removed one or two extra variables:

```
def devinettes():
    nombre = random.randint(1, 100)
    compteur = 1
    total = []
    premieressaie = ""
    message = ""
    print("J'ai choisi un nombre aléatoire de 1 à 100 inclusivement \n\
et je vous invite à deviner de quel nombre il s'agit.")
    while True:
        try:
            tentative = int(input("Votre essai svp: "))
            total.append(tentative)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Ceci n'est pas un nombre entier.")
    while tentative != nombre:
        if tentative < 0:
            print("Bon, vous en avez assez, ça se voit...")
            sys.exit()
        elif tentative > nombre:
            print("Trop grand! ")
        elif tentative < nombre:
            print("Trop petit! ")
        while True:
            try:
                tentative = int(input("Votre essai svp: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Ceci n'est pas un nombre entier.")
        compteur += 1
        liste = tentative
        total.append(tentative)

    message = ' '.join([str(essai) for essai in total])
    print("Bravo vous avez devinez mon choix après", "\x1b[0;33;40m" + str(compteur) + "\x1b[0m",\
"\x1b[0;33;40m"+ "essais!" + "\x1b[0m", "\nVos essais:", message)
    reessaie = recommence()
    return reessaie
```

I've played two games with this, and it works correctly.  For instance:

```
J'ai choisi un nombre aléatoire de 1 à 100 inclusivement 
et je vous invite à deviner de quel nombre il s'agit.
Votre essai svp: 50
Trop petit! 
Votre essai svp: 75
Trop petit! 
Votre essai svp: 88
Trop grand! 
Votre essai svp: 81
Trop grand! 
Votre essai svp: 78
Trop petit! 
Votre essai svp: 79
Trop petit! 
Votre essai svp: 80
Bravo vous avez devinez mon choix après 7 essais! 
Vos essais: 50 75 88 81 78 79 80
Rejouer (o/n) ?
```